# When I run Android SDK from terminal, it shows error. How to fix it?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3550 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:328)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:316)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:118)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:101)
```

Comment: What command are you running, exactly? (You can edit your question to provide this information.)

Answer (score 6):

Credit to [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=3163174b4c3e470322b8cf977d6f0d39&p=11099532&postcount=2):

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

aptitude search swt-gtk based on the search result, I would presume that
installing libswt-gtk-3-java would fix your problem.

If not try the -jni or -gcj version.  I believe one of those should fix your stack trace.